# QuickType Bar on the Keyboard

Tags: ios8, uikeyboard, quicktypebar

As you all might be knowing about the new Quick Type bar on the keyboard.

In my application , I have put a custom TextView bar on the keyboard. But because of **QuickType Bar** , my textview gets hidden.

I want to know , Is there any property or method to know whether the QuickType Bar is open or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)keyboardFrameChanged:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGPoint from = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;
    CGPoint to = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;


    float height = 0.0f;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        height = to.x - from.x;
    } else {
        height = to.y - from.y;
    }

    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + height)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing which can tell you whether the QuickType bar is active or not but you can register for the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification with this code and with that you can get info about the height of the keyboard.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Use the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` values in the passed `userInfo` dictionary to retrieve the current and future frames of the keyboard. You can use the following code as a reference.

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
     NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
     CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
     // Manage your other frame changes
}
```

Hope this helps. It will get called every time the keyboard changes its frame.

Comment: Thanks @Bhumit. I too tried than , with UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification . I am posting my try below. So that it can be helpful to others too.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have suggested, the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` will fire every time the keyboard gets a new frame. This includes when the keyboard will show and hide, and when the QuickType bar will show and hide.

The thing is, this is exactly the same notification as the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, just with a different name. **Therefore, if you're already implementing a method for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, you're good to go.**

**With one exception, though.** When you get the keyboard frame in your method for handling the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, you must make sure you access it via the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`, not the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`. Otherwise, it will get the correct frame when the keyboard is shown/hidden, but not when the QuickType bar is.

So, the code in your method for handling the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` should look something like this (in Swift):

```swift
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    keyboardRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    keyboardRect = yourView.convertRect(keyboardRect, fromView: nil)

    // Handling the keyboard rect by changing frames, content offsets, constraints, or whatever
}
```