# iOS8 keyboard quicktype activate/deactivate events

Tags: keyboard, ios8

I have an issue where I move my view on keyboard appeared event and also my view has a text view at bottom, it's a chat screen.
Now my problem is that when keyboard appeared in iOS 8 with quicktype my compose view which is at bottom gets hidden. So I need to move view again if when type appears and reposition when quick type moves away.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to detect when the keyboard frame has changed, and then readjust your view accordingly.  See this solution [QuickType Bar on the Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034997/quicktype-bar-on-the-keyboard)

If you already have an NSNotification that detects when your keyboard will be shown, then you can accomplish it this way.

```
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

//this part detects the height of your keyboard, whether quicktype is open or not
NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize keyboardSize = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
float keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;

//animate message bar - this animation code works if autolayout is on
[self.messageBarView layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:[aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue] animations:^{
    self.bottomConstraintMsgView.constant = keyboardHeight;
    [self.messageBarView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

}

The important part is when you are declaring the "CGSize keyboardSize".  You have to use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey as I did above.  This will give you the frame size after the frame change (quicktype hide/show) has completed.

Comment: I have tried same approach, but its difficult to identify whether Quick type enabled or disabled, so add to your answer which is Quite helpful (Thanks & I appreciate your answer:) ) we got to keep track of previous frame and new frame. With the difference which is to be calculated as below comment. P.S.

Comment: NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGPoint begin = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;
        CGPoint end = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].origin;

        if(begin.y > end.y)// QuickType is pulled up
        {
            iIsQuickTypeActive = YES;
        }
        else if(begin.y < end.y)// QuickType is dragged down
        {
            iIsQuickTypeActive = NO;
        }