# How do I determine if QuickType chat is off?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

An alternative to having a constant height would be to disable QuickType bar in iOS 8 WITHOUT disabling autocorrect, but I don't think that's possible..

Answer (score 1):

You add notification when keyboard change it's height. there you can check height and determine quicktype is hidden /unhide. Goto below link.

**Refer:** [QuickType Bar on the Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034997/quicktype-bar-on-the-keyboard)